# How best to call a dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script which is quite a beefy select statement and the format of it is as below.
It works perfectly well as a standalone script, but the local variable and temporary table restrictions in functions and views are preventing me from adding it to a database. What is the best way of creating this dynamic data which I can call in the FROM clause of a stored procedure without using functionality that was not available prior to SQL2005?

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(CARE_ID int NOT NULL,EVENT_DATE datetime NULL,EVENT_ID int NULL,EVENT_TYPE varchar(20))

CREATE TABLE t2
(CARE_ID int NOT NULL,EVENT_DATE datetime NULL,EVENT_ID int NULL,EVENT_TYPE varchar(20))

INSERT INTO t1
SELECT STATEMENT GOES HERE

INSERT INTO t2
SELECT STATEMENT GOES HERE


SELECT * FROM anotherTable
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM t2

DROP TABLE t1
DROP TABLE t2
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem?, I don't see any dynamic SQL whatsoever here

Comment: Why not create indexed views for t1/t2 instead of temporary tables? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx.  Can't think of anything else given limited problem definition.

Comment: You can use temp tables or a table variable in 2k or greater.  See http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Comment: @xQbert - Yes, thank you, I took the additional view route in the end. I was trying to avoid it initially as I knew it would be a bigger hit on the database by unioning three views, and so it has proved with a 16% increase in reads, but I'm hoping that users can swallow it. Cheers.

Comment: Note I mentioned indexed views (greater performance) a regular view would still be sluggish.

Comment: Those `UNION`s are going to hurt performance. If you insist on refactoring this to a function outside of the SP, `INSERT` both t1 & t2's `SELECT`s in to the same tabular object (killing one `UNION`) - and use `UNION ALL` if you're ok with the difference. But I would really try to include this logic in the SP and use temp tables, especially if the data mass is high and in the event you require indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft introduced table variables with SQL Server 2000 as an alternative to using temporary tables.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    CARE_ID int NOT NULL,
    EVENT_DATE datetime NULL,
    EVENT_ID int NULL,
    EVENT_TYPE varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT STATEMENT GOES HERE
```

These are perfectly suitable for use within a stored procedure.

Comment: This is a specific example of what @bsivel suggested.